# A pointer to array of pointers to function

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers, implicit-conversion

Let's say I have a function

```
int foo(void)
{
    printf("Hello world");
}
```

And I want to use a pointer to a function to point to `foo()`.

`typedef int (*f_ptr)(void);`

Which one of those cases would I use for that purpose?

```
(A) f_ptr my_ptr = foo;
    my_ptr();

(B) f_ptr * my_ptr = foo;
    my_ptr();
```

Now if I have 10 functions `foo1(), foo2() .. foo10()` and I want to put them in an array and iterate through the array using a pointer to function, how would I do it?

```
f_ptr my_functions[10] =
{
    foo1,
    foo2,
    ..
    foo10,
};

(A) f_ptr my_ptr = my_functions;   
(B) f_ptr * my_ptr = my_functions;

    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        my_ptr();
        my_ptr++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters pay attention to that though this function

```
int foo(void)
{
    printf("Hello world");
}
```

has the return type `int` it returns nothing. Instead you could write for example

```
int foo(void)
{
    return printf("Hello world");
}
```

Nevertheless an array designator used in expressions with rare exceptions is converted to pointer to its first element.

So if the element type of the array

```
f_ptr my_functions[10];
```

is `f_ptr` then a pointer to elements of the array will look like

```
f_ptr * my_ptr = my_functions;
```

So for example you can write a loop using the pointer like

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{
    my_ptr[i]();
}
```

Or

```
for ( f_ptr *my_ptr = my_functions; my_ptr != my_functions + 10; ++my_ptr )
{
    ( *my_ptr )();
}
```

Comment: @TomKarzes Reread the title of the question one more.

Comment: I guess it's not clear what OP really wants.  The description and the example don't match.

Comment: @TomKarzes Usually beginners do not know exactly what they need.

Comment: Ok, I think I got my answer! Thanks! Yes you are right about the return type in the example, I was just trying to think of an example quickly. Thank you!